# Are the relations $\ln (e^{\widehat A}) = \widehat A$ and $e^{\ln \widehat A} = \widehat A$ true for operators?

Tags: operators, mathematics

For the real numbers, $x\in \mathbb R$, we have the relations $$\ln (e^x) = x = e^{\ln x}.$$ Since operators aren't numbers, these equations don't necessarily hold for operators, that is, if we replace $x$ with an operator $\widehat A$. So my question is: Are these relations valid for operators? And why / why not?

My attempt to far:

As far as I know, operator functions used in quantum mechanics are defined as a power series expansion of that function, using the operator as the argument:

$$e^{\widehat B} \equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{\widehat B}^n}{n!}.$$

For  $\ln x$  I found different power series for different domains of $x$, for example the series

$$\ln x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2n-1} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2n-1},$$

which is valid for $x>0$ . But my attempt to use these power series (and I'm not even sure what it would mean for an operator to be greater than $0$, as required by this log series) goes nowhere useful:

\begin{align*} e^{\ln \widehat A} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\ln\widehat A)^n}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2k-1} \left(\frac{\widehat A-1}{\widehat A+1}\right)^{2k-1} \right)^n \\
&\stackrel ?= \widehat A
\end{align*}

I can't see whether those power series reduce to just $\widehat A$ or not. Any help or clarification is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The second equality in OP's first eq. is not true for $x=0$.

Comment: For hermitean operators, or diagonalizable ones, such relations may hold, if they hold for their eigenvalues, The exponential is fine, but the [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) may have subtleties, since the [complex logarithm is multivalued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)...

Comment: The first relation in the title is not true even for complex numbers: $\ln(\exp(4i))=4i-2i\pi\ne4i$. So, for example, the operator $4i\hat E$ (where $\hat E$ is the identity operator) doesn't obey this relation.

Comment: @Ruslan It definitely does obey the relation if one chooses an appropriate branch of the complex logarithm.

Comment: @BobKnighton the fact that you need to switch from the principal branch to retain the relation is already something that must make you think twice before considering even more complicated objects than complex numbers. And in any case, unless you take logarithm as a multifunction, it'd be hard to work with general operator $ir\hat E$ for $r\in\mathbb R$ in the context of this relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QM most operators are Hermitean, and thus diagonalizable, $\hat A= U^\dagger D U$, for some unitary *U* and real diagonal *D*. So all your series expressions $f(\hat A)=0$ are essentially $U^\dagger f(D) U=0$, that is, a tower of the same relations for each diagonal component of *D*, each eigenvalue.

If it so happens that all eigenvalues of $\hat A$ are positive definite, your equation holds (if your respective expansion expression held for each one of them), otherwise you must be very careful with logarithms, a tall order: hardly realistic. (Exponentials, however, are normally fine, since they are 
single-valued functions. It is the logarithms that are dangerous. See WP article [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix).)

If you are sure $\hat A$ has no null eigenvectors, but have doubts about the sign of its real eigenvalues, consider $\hat {A} \hat A $ instead, whose eigenvalues are guaranteed to be positive definite.

To get a grip on your procedures, practice with, e.g. $\hat A = \sigma_1$, so $D=\sigma_3$, and $\hat A \hat A = 1\!\!1$. You readily see how your hyperbolic tangent expansion is aggressively ill-defined for $\hat A$ but fine, and trivial, for its square.

Comment: What do you mean by $A$ in your "consider $\hat A  A$ instead"?

Comment: @Ruslan Typo; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the Taylor expansion does not work with operators for many reasons (especially problem with domains), unless the operator is (a) everywhere defined and (b) bounded.

In this case, $e^A$ can be safely defined via Taylor expansion, whereas $\ln A$ also requires $||A-I||< 1$ (exactly as for complex numbers and I am thinking here of the standard expansion of $\ln(1+y)$ for $|y| <1$, your series needs a more difficult analysis because it is not a power series and one cannot automatically extend the popular results from complex numbers to operators). The inversion formulas are valid accordingly.

In case $A: D(A) \to H$ is closed and normal ($D(A)$ is a dense subspace of $H$ and *normal* means $A^\dagger A = AA^\dagger$, and this is true in particular if $A$ is selfadjoint) then one can exploit the standard *functional calculus* based on the *spectral theorem*.

Under the said hypotheses, the *spectral decomposition* holds
$$A = \int_{\sigma(A)} z dP^{(A)}(z)$$
where $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb{C}$ is the spectrum of $A$.

Here one can define 
$$e^A := \int_{\sigma(A)} e^z dP^{(A)}(z)$$
and (paying attention to to the fact that $\ln$ is multivalued on $\mathbb{C}$, so that some precautions need if $\sigma(A)$ for instance includes the semiaxis $Re z <0$), 
$$ \ln A := \int_{\sigma(A)} \ln z dP^{(A)}(z)\:.$$
Regarding domains, it turns out that
$$D(f(A)) = \left\{x \in H \:\left|\: \int_{\sigma(A)} |f(z)|^2 d\mu_{x,x}(z)\right.< +\infty\right\}$$
where the complex measure appearing in the right-hand side is defined as
$$\mu_{x,y}(E) = \langle x|P^{(A)}_E y\rangle$$
for every Borel set  $E \subset \mathbb{C}$.

It turns out that, if $D(A)=H$ and $||A|| <+\infty$, then the above definition coincides to the Taylor-expansion definition.

Since, when the written composition makes sense, it holds 
$$\int_{\sigma(A)} f(g(z)) dP^{(A)}(z) = \int_{\sigma(A)} f(z) dP^{(g(A))}(z) $$
you can conclude that 
$e^{\ln A}= A$ and $\ln e^A =A$
provided the relevant left-hand side is well defined, according to the discussion above.